# GuzzleHTTP Client base_uri incorrect from what is passed in

Tags: php, guzzle

I am trying to set the base URI for API requests on my GuzzleHTTP instance but am having issues with it dropping the path. According to the docs, a URI of `https://api.app.com/v2/` should return that as the path but on my project it is dropping the `v2` and just returning `https://api.app.com`

```
$this->client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => $this->baseUri // baseUri == https://api.app.com/v2/
]);
```

`base_uri` should be `https://api.app.com/v2/` not `https://api.app.com`

Comment: May you add a little more context? You create a new client and then? How do you issue the request? Have you a slash in front of the relative url [http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html?highlight=base_uri](is this the docs you refer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was coming from the way I was running a request. I was prepending a `/` onto the endpoint and according to the docs, you need to omit this in order to properly request while using `base_uri`

So instead of  `$this->client->get('/endpoint')` it needs to be `$this->client->get('endpoint')`